# How to do trigger for text rich when checkbox is true?

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, checkbox

What I'm trying to do is that when a checkbox is true, my rich-text area is required to have image but when I run this code, it still can proceed even no image in that rich-text area.

Kindly help me to fix this :(

my checkbox: TSM_Email__c 
my rich text area: Attachment__c

So here is my current code and it pop out this error message.. is there any problem with my code?

```
trigger PraTrigger on I4_0_Project_Request_And_Approval__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (I4_0_Project_Request_And_Approval__c p:Trigger.new){
        
        String picString = p.Attachment__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
        if((p.TSM_Email__c == true) && (picString == null)){
                p.addError('Picture is required to proceed');
            }
            
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Based on that trigger logic, any `I4_0_Project_Request_And_Approval__c` record would throw an error when updated. Have you tried adding any sort of debugging to see if the trigger code is being fired at all?

Comment: Is this the full code of the logic? Because you have added `addError` in both if and else, so  practically any updation on the record should fail.

Comment: Yes, this is the full code but i have amended a bit.. adding before insert and it fired my code but if didnt put any image in the rich text, i come out an error from the code execution.. can see it in my edited code

Answer (score 0):

If `Attachment__c` is null/blank, your code will throw a [NullPointerException](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327918&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1). You need to check that there's any value in the field before checking if it contains/does not contain a certain string/value. Not to mention, if it is null (which means it has no img) - you need to also add the error. In other words, you have 2 conditions to check where you want an error

1. if the checkbox is true and the rich text is not filled out at all - add error
2. if the checkbox is true and the rich text is filled out without an image - add error

In code, it looks like this where you can make use of [String.isBlank](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isBlank)

```
for (I4_0_Project_Request_And_Approval__c p:Trigger.new){
    if(p.TSM_Email__c && (String.isBlank(p.Attachment__c) || (String.isNotBlank(p.Attachment__c) && !p.Attachment__c.contains('<img')))){
        p.addError('Picture is required to proceed');
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Hi Kris, I've tried this one but it doesnt fire this logic.. i can save when i checked the box even got no image

Comment: I updated it to handle the scenario you're actually testing which is filling out nothing in the `Attachment__c` field.

Comment: Hi Kris. It works!! Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated ><